# chromedriver.quit and chromedriver.close doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I am on an interactive prompt and I have excecute the essential commands, the minimum indispensable ones:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options) #Chrome has opened
driver.quit #doesn't work
driver.close #doesn't work
```

The error messages are the following:

```
<bound method WebDriver.quit of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="34e01ec73c9522d792c5b0e13797c8d4")>>

<bound method WebDriver.close of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="34e01ec73c9522d792c5b0e13797c8d4")>>
```

Why?

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit Desktop
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
selenium 3.141.0 (installed from pip3 21.0.1)
ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23
Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90

So everything to the latest version.

Comment: .quit() and .close() missing the ().

Comment: Oh sorry, what a fool I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already good result above that you should use quit(), not quit, and close(), not close,

as well try to use Options() instead of ChromeOptions()

so, the code looks like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options) #Chrome has opened
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

`driver.quit()` and `driver.close()` are methods. Call them as methods.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are just missing `()`
So just use `driver.quit()` and it will work correctly.